# Default Commit behavior of MongoOperations without explicit Transaction Support

Tags: mongodb, commit, spring-data-mongodb

What is the default commit behavior in `spring-data-mongodb`, if one uses `@Autowired MongoOperations` without using `@Transactional` and without explicit `MongoTransactionManager` Bean initialization in code?

We can see if the MongoTxnMgr is used along with @Transaction support, `autocommit:false` is visible in `org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command` in the logs followed by an explicit `commitTransaction` afterwards;

However when it is not used, `autocommit` is absent from the same command. In such scenario, when exactly the `commit` takes place?

We are using Mongo 4.X Server, spring-data-mongodb 2.2.5 RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB 4.X behavior from a client perspective using an explicit transaction mechanism or without is clarified in this [discussion](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/default-commit-behavior-mongo-4-x/125859)

Excerpt - For MongoDB 4.X

> for a user you should consider that any write outside of the transaction is autocommited by default. So each atomic write is either fully stored or discarded.